# Best Practice Instrumenting a Webpage when having parallel tasks

Tags: c#, asp.net, trace, parallel-processing, instrumentation

I try to get an understanding of the performance of a web page and use Trace.Write

Problem is that I use Parallel.Invoke and starts more threads where I would like to report back using Trace.Write

```
            Parallel.Invoke(() => Chart1AndLegend(param),
                () => Chart2(param),
                () => Chart3(param),
                () => Chart4(param));
```

I have realized that Trace.Write is not a good way of tracing as it is gives you the time since last entry which makes no sense if more threads are writing ..

Question: Any good suggestion how to instrument a page when using Parallel library or do I need to write my own tracing!?!?

Comment: I know this is quite late. However - was wondering if you looked at the Task Framework for this. I feel with the Tasks you can specify delegate which can be used to trace out what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be stating the obvious here, but what if you created a StopWatch (or a number of) and simply write the elapsed time in the Trace.Write message? I suppose the other thing would be identifying what thread/method you're in the trace category (use Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId).

Alternatively, you'll need to use something else like Enterprise Library, log4net or the tracing in System.Diagnostics (see http://www.15seconds.com/issue/020910.htm for a full discussion of tracing in System.Diagnostics).

Comment: Yes I did my tracing with stopwatch.